Create channel and join error: Create channel error:


Create channel and join error: Create channel error: error should be nil for SaveChannel of orgchannel: create channel failed: create channel failed: SendEnvelope failed: calling orderer 'orderer1.example.com:7050' failed: Orderer Client Status Code: (2) CONNECTION_FAILED. Description: dialing connection on target [orderer1.example.com:7050]: connection is in TRANSIENT_FAILURE



version: 1.0.0

#不改
client:
  organization: org1

  logging:
    level: info

  cryptoconfig:
    path: /mnt/hgfs/learn_fabric_vmshare/org5/fixtures/crypto-config

  credentialStore:
    path: "/tmp/state-store"
    cryptoStore:
      path: /tmp/msp

  BCCSP:
    security:
     enabled: true
     default:
      provider: "SW"
     hashAlgorithm: "SHA2"
     softVerify: true
     level: 256

  tlsCerts:
    systemCertPool: true
    client:
      key:
#        tls私钥
        path: /mnt/hgfs/learn_fabric_vmshare/org5/fixtures/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/User1@org1.example.com/tls/client.key
      cert:
#        tls公钥
        path: /mnt/hgfs/learn_fabric_vmshare/org5/fixtures/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/User1@org1.example.com/tls/client.crt

#改
channels:
  mychannel:
    peers:
      peer0.org1.example.com:
        endorsingPeer: true
        chaincodeQuery: true
        ledgerQuery: true
        eventSource: true

      peer1.org1.example.com:
        endorsingPeer: true
        chaincodeQuery: true
        ledgerQuery: true
        eventSource: true

      peer0.org2.example.com:
        endorsingPeer: true
        chaincodeQuery: true
        ledgerQuery: true
        eventSource: true

      peer1.org2.example.com:
        endorsingPeer: true
        chaincodeQuery: true
        ledgerQuery: true
        eventSource: true

      peer0.org3.example.com:
        endorsingPeer: true
        chaincodeQuery: true
        ledgerQuery: true
        eventSource: true

      peer1.org3.example.com:
        endorsingPeer: true
        chaincodeQuery: true
        ledgerQuery: true
        eventSource: true

      peer0.org4.example.com:
        endorsingPeer: true
        chaincodeQuery: true
        ledgerQuery: true
        eventSource: true

      peer1.org4.example.com:
        endorsingPeer: true
        chaincodeQuery: true
        ledgerQuery: true
        eventSource: true

    policies:
      queryChannelConfig:
        minResponses: 1
        maxTargets: 1
        retryOpts:
          attempts: 5
          initialBackoff: 500ms
          maxBackoff: 5s
          backoffFactor: 2.0

#改
organizations:
  org1:
    mspid: Org1MSP
    cryptoPath:  peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/{username}@org1.example.com/msp
    peers:
      - peer0.org1.example.com
      - peer1.org1.example.com

  org2:
    mspid: Org2MSP
    cryptoPath:  peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/users/{username}@org2.example.com/msp
    peers:
      - peer0.org2.example.com
      - peer1.org2.example.com

  org3:
    mspid: Org3MSP
    cryptoPath:  peerOrganizations/org3.example.com/users/{username}@org3.example.com/msp
    peers:
      - peer0.org3.example.com
      - peer1.org3.example.com

  org4:
    mspid: Org4MSP
    cryptoPath:  peerOrganizations/org4.example.com/users/{username}@org4.example.com/msp
    peers:
      - peer0.org4.example.com
      - peer1.org4.example.com
  
  ordererorg:
      mspID: OrdererMSP
      cryptoPath: ordererOrganizations/example.com/users/{username}@example.com/msp

#不改
orderers:

  orderer1.example.com:
#    url: orderer1.example.com:7050
    url: localhost:7050
    grpcOptions:
      ssl-target-name-override: orderer1.example.com
      keep-alive-time: 0s
      keep-alive-timeout: 20s
      keep-alive-permit: false
      fail-fast: false
      allow-insecure: false
    tlsCACerts:
      path: /mnt/hgfs/learn_fabric_vmshare/org5/fixtures/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/tlsca/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem
      
  orderer2.example.com:
    url: orderer2.example.com:8050
    grpcOptions:
      ssl-target-name-override: orderer2.example.com
      keep-alive-time: 0s
      keep-alive-timeout: 20s
      keep-alive-permit: false
      fail-fast: false
      allow-insecure: false
    tlsCACerts:
      path: /mnt/hgfs/learn_fabric_vmshare/org5/fixtures/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/tlsca/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem
  
  orderer3.example.com:
    url: orderer3.example.com:9050
    grpcOptions:
      ssl-target-name-override: orderer3.example.com
      keep-alive-time: 0s
      keep-alive-timeout: 20s
      keep-alive-permit: false
      fail-fast: false
      allow-insecure: false
    tlsCACerts:
      path: /mnt/hgfs/learn_fabric_vmshare/org5/fixtures/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/tlsca/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem

#改
peers:
  peer0.org1.example.com:
    url: peer0.org1.example.com:7051
    grpcOptions:
      ssl-target-name-override: peer0.org1.example.com
      keep-alive-time: 0s
      keep-alive-timeout: 30s
      keep-alive-permit: false
      fail-fast: false
      allow-insecure: false
    tlsCACerts:
      path: /mnt/hgfs/learn_fabric_vmshare/org5/fixtures/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/tlsca/tlsca.org1.example.com-cert.pem

  peer1.org1.example.com:
    url: peer1.org1.example.com:7061
    grpcOptions:
      ssl-target-name-override: peer1.org1.example.com
      keep-alive-time: 0s
      keep-alive-timeout: 30s
      keep-alive-permit: false
      fail-fast: false
      allow-insecure: false
    tlsCACerts:
      path: /mnt/hgfs/learn_fabric_vmshare/org5/fixtures/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/tlsca/tlsca.org1.example.com-cert.pem

  peer0.org2.example.com:
    url: peer0.org2.example.com:8051
    grpcOptions:
      ssl-target-name-override: peer0.org2.example.com
      keep-alive-time: 0s
      keep-alive-timeout: 30s
      keep-alive-permit: false
      fail-fast: false
      allow-insecure: false
    tlsCACerts:
      path: /mnt/hgfs/learn_fabric_vmshare/org5/fixtures/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/tlsca/tlsca.org2.example.com-cert.pem

  peer1.org2.example.com:
    url: peer1.org2.example.com:8061
    grpcOptions:
      ssl-target-name-override: peer1.org2.example.com
      keep-alive-time: 0s
      keep-alive-timeout: 30s
      keep-alive-permit: false
      fail-fast: false
      allow-insecure: false
    tlsCACerts:
      path: /mnt/hgfs/learn_fabric_vmshare/org5/fixtures/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/tlsca/tlsca.org2.example.com-cert.pem

  peer0.org3.example.com: #1
    url: peer0.org3.example.com:9051 #2
    grpcOptions:
      ssl-target-name-override: peer0.org3.example.com #1
      keep-alive-time: 0s
      keep-alive-timeout: 30s
      keep-alive-permit: false
      fail-fast: false
      allow-insecure: false
    tlsCACerts:
      path: /mnt/hgfs/learn_fabric_vmshare/org5/fixtures/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org3.example.com/tlsca/tlsca.org3.example.com-cert.pem #2

  peer1.org3.example.com: #1
    url: peer1.org3.example.com:9061 #2
    grpcOptions:
      ssl-target-name-override: peer1.org3.example.com #1
      keep-alive-time: 0s
      keep-alive-timeout: 30s
      keep-alive-permit: false
      fail-fast: false
      allow-insecure: false
    tlsCACerts:
      path: /mnt/hgfs/learn_fabric_vmshare/org5/fixtures/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org3.example.com/tlsca/tlsca.org3.example.com-cert.pem #2

  peer0.org4.example.com: #1
    url: peer0.org4.example.com:9051 #2
    grpcOptions:
      ssl-target-name-override: peer0.org4.example.com #1
      keep-alive-time: 0s
      keep-alive-timeout: 30s
      keep-alive-permit: false
      fail-fast: false
      allow-insecure: false
    tlsCACerts:
      path: /mnt/hgfs/learn_fabric_vmshare/org5/fixtures/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org4.example.com/tlsca/tlsca.org4.example.com-cert.pem #2

  peer1.org4.example.com: #1
    url: peer1.org4.example.com:9061 #2
    grpcOptions:
      ssl-target-name-override: peer1.org4.example.com #1
      keep-alive-time: 0s
      keep-alive-timeout: 30s
      keep-alive-permit: false
      fail-fast: false
      allow-insecure: false
    tlsCACerts:
      path: /mnt/hgfs/learn_fabric_vmshare/org5/fixtures/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org4.example.com/tlsca/tlsca.org4.example.com-cert.pem #2


#改
entityMatchers:
  peer:
    - pattern: (\w+).org1.example.com:(\d+)
      urlSubstitutionExp: ${1}.org1.example.com:${2}
      sslTargetOverrideUrlSubstitutionExp: ${1}.org1.example.com
      mappedHost: peer0.org1.example.com

    - pattern: (\w+).org2.example.com:(\d+)
      urlSubstitutionExp: ${1}.org2.example.com:${2}
      sslTargetOverrideUrlSubstitutionExp: ${1}.org2.example.com
      mappedHost: peer0.org2.example.com

    - pattern: (\w+).org3.example.com:(\d+)
      urlSubstitutionExp: ${1}.org3.example.com:${2}
      sslTargetOverrideUrlSubstitutionExp: ${1}.org3.example.com
      mappedHost: peer0.org3.example.com
      
    - pattern: (\w+).org4.example.com:(\d+)
      urlSubstitutionExp: ${1}.org4.example.com:${2}
      sslTargetOverrideUrlSubstitutionExp: ${1}.org4.example.com
      mappedHost: peer0.org4.example.com

  orderer:
    - pattern: (\w+).example.(\w+)
      urlSubstitutionExp: orderer1.example.com:7050
      sslTargetOverrideUrlSubstitutionExp: orderer1.example.com
      mappedHost: orderer1.example.com
  

